References for $\mathsf{PSPACE} \neq \mathsf{E}$ and $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NTIME}(n^k)$
In a recent blog post, Lance Fortnow dropped as a little exercise the task of proving $\mathsf{PSPACE} \neq \mathsf{E}$, using the fact that $\mathsf{EXP}$ is the closure of $\mathsf{E}$ under poly-time many-one reductions, together with the Time Hierarchy Theorem. Do we know of a reference for this observation, or is it just folklore?
Similarly, it feels like an analogous argument gives you $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NTIME}(n^k)$ for every fixed $k$, arguing that $\mathsf{NP}$ is the closure of $\mathsf{NTIME}(n^k)$ under poly-time many-one reductions. This surprised me a bit, since I thought we only knew how to prove $\mathsf{P}\neq\mathsf{NTIME}(n)$ and that argument broke for anything superlinear. Do we have a reference for this (or am I mistaken and this doesn't follow)? (The Complexity Zoo's entry for $\mathsf{NTIME}(n)$ points to the result $\mathsf{DTIME}(n) \subsetneq \mathsf{NTIME}(n)$, which does not work for arbitrary $f(n)$, but doesn't say anything about the separations from $\mathsf{P}$.)

Re: 2nd para. Indeed $P \neq NTIME(n^k)$ by the same argument (P is closed under P reductions, NTIME(n^k) isn't), but, as Lance says in his blog post about PSPACE vs E, this argument doesn't tell you which (if any) is larger. It is still possible that P is (properly) contained in NTIME(n^k) (though it is not in NTIME(n), by [PPST]).

Good, thanks! Yes, this is exactly what I had in mind. So I guess these are just folklore, good to know.

I mean, at this point it is folklore I guess, but I wouldn't be surprised if these occur in one of the early complexity papers, say where they first prove the Time Hierarchy or Nondet Time Hierarchy, or first introduced the class E.

Here are some papers that have results similar to the ones you ask about.
Ronald V. Book, On Languages Accepted in Polynomial Time, SIAM J. Comput. 1, 1972, pp. 281-287.
In this paper, we find Theorem 2 (There is no pair of real numbers r and s such that DSPACE($n^r$) $\subseteq$ P $\subseteq$ DSPACE($n^s$). (and similarly for NP).  In particular, neither P nor NP is equal to the class of context-sensitive languages.  Also, the Corollary after Theorem 3 says (in modern notation) E is not equal to NP.
A related paper is:
Ronald V. Book, Comparing Complexity Classes, J. Comput. and System Sciences 9, 1974, pp. 213-229.
In this paper, the Corollary at the top of page 223 says that P is not equal to NTIME(n^k) for any k.
Another Corollary lower down on the page states that E is not equal to PSPACE.  And on the next page we learn that NE is not equal to PSPACE and NE is not equal to EXP, and it is stated that some of these results also appear in Ron Fagin's Ph.D. Dissertation.
At one point in time, all of this was new and (even) surprising.
